# How does bicubic interpolation work?

Tags: image-processing, interpolation, pixel, bicubic

After reading text about this said topic, i found out that it considers 16 of the original neighboring pixels. What i want to know is how does it compute the color value of the new pixel. If the color values of the 16 pixels are known, how could you compute the value of the new one?

Comment: It looks like you are specifying an RGB triplet for a single pixel, and not the 16 neighboring pixels like you mentioned.

Comment: to make things clear, can you give me a concrete example on how would you compute the new color of the interpolated pixel.(pixel by pixel RGB computation)

Answer (score 12):

I think it's pretty well explained in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation). You need the intensity values of 4*4=16 pixels, from which you can calculate the interpolated value at any point *within* that 4*4 grid.

If you mean how to do this for RGB triplets, you just do the process separately for each component.

Comment: what i need is pixel level computation. can you give me a concrete example