# Increase image size, without messing up clarity

Tags: image-processing

Are there libraries, scripts or any techniques to increase image size in height and width....

or you must need to have a super good resolution image for it?.....

Comment: What they do in CSI is not possible in real life.

Comment: As much as I agree with you, this probably should have been a comment.

Comment: @Cody BAM!  And so it is!  Probably the most useful update to the mod tools yet!

Answer (score 1):

**[Bicubic interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation)** is pretty much the best you're going to get when it comes to increasing image size while maintaining as much of the original detail as possible. It's not yet possible to work the actual magic that your question would require.

The Wikipedia link above is a pretty solid reference, but there was a question asked about how it works here on Stack Overflow: [How does bicubic interpolation work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979095/how-bicubic-interpolation-work)

This is the highest quality resampling algorithm that Photoshop (and other graphic software) offers. Generally, it's recommended that you use bicubic *smoothing* when you're *increasing* image size, and bicubic *sharpening* when you're *reducing* image size. Sharpening can produce an over-sharpened image when you are enlarging an image, so you need to be careful.

As far as libraries or scripts, it's difficult to recommend anything without knowing what language you're intending to do this in. But I can guarantee that there's an image processing library including this algorithm already around for any of the popular languages—I wouldn't advise reimplementing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing height & width of an image means one of two things:
i) You are increasing the physical size of the image (i.e. cm or inches), without touching its content.

ii) You are trying to increase the image pixel content (ie its resolution)

So:
(i) has to do with rendering. As the image physical size goes up, you are drawing larger pixels (the DPI goes down). Good if you want to look at the image from far away (sau on a really large screen). If look at it from up close, you are going to see mostly large dots.

(ii) Is just plainly impossible. Say your image is 100X100 pixels and you want to  make 200x200. This means you start from 10,000 pixels, end up with 40,000... what are you going to put in the 30,000 new pixels? Whatever your answer, you are going to end up with 30,000 invented pixels and the image you get is going to be either fuzzier, or faker, and usually both. All the techniques that increase an image size use some sort of average among neighboring pixel values, which amounts to "fuzzier".

Cheers.

Comment: @user309010: The answer says option 2 "is just plainly impossible", so you ask if there are any OS technologies that can do this? Do you know what [impossible](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/impossible) means?